# Integrate SignalR core version into SPA Core

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I'm just want to ask you. SignalR now in alpha. And as I understand now in  SPA Core version you have only old version of signalr, that won't work on linux. Is there any way to replace old version to new one? Or if you have roadmap on it, when are you planing to implement it in core version?

Comment: Track this feature request: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2585#issuecomment-344292346

Comment: Track this pull request: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/2790

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now [download](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates) `v3.4.1` of the template with the [Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR) preview.

Read the documentation for [SignalR AspNetCore Integration](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/SignalR-AspNetCore-Integration).

Comment: Thank. But i already integrate it. Because had no time to wait when asked.